# Electrostatic force for a system of constant potentials

Tags: electrostatics

I am confused about the following: In discussion of electrostatic forces for a system of fixed potential in “[Field and Wave Electromagnetics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201128195)” , there are two equations: (3-189) gives the total energy “supplied” by the external source to the system (please see the attached fig) and (3-191) shows the change in electrostatic energy of the system.  How are these two different and how are equations (3-190) and (3-191) added to give (3-189)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an example will help?

Consider a parallel plate capacitor $C$ which has a constant voltage source $V$ connected across it and the charge on the capacitor is $Q$.
Let the plates have a separation of $x$, an area $A$ with the relative permittivity of the material between the plates $\epsilon_0$.
This arrangement is the system under consideration.

What will happen if the separation of the plates is changed by an amount $dx$?
A charge $dQ$ will flow in the circuit.

The work done by the battery in moving a charge $\delta Q$ is $V\delta Q$ and this is what is called in the passage $dW_{\rm s}$ the energy supplied by the sources.

The change in the electric potential energy stored in the system is $\frac 12 V dq$ and this is what is called $W_{\rm e}$ in the book.

Now there is a force between those parallel plates and that force does $F \delta x$ amount of work and this is $dW$ in the book, the work done by the system.

Using the conservation of energy gives the relationship.

$\text{work done by the battery}$
$= \text{change in electric potential energy} + \text{mechanical work done by the system}$

$$dW_{\rm s}  = dW_{\rm e} + dW$$

As in the book I have been vague about the direction of movement so let the separation of the plates be decreased.

For the parallel plate arrangement $Q= \dfrac{\epsilon_0 A}{x}V$

If the separation $x$ is decreased then as the potential difference across the parallel plates is constant the charge on the plates must increase.
So the battery moves charge from its positive terminal to its negative terminal and does positive work, to $W_{\rm s}$ is positive.

The electric potential energy of the system increases so $dW_{\rm e}$ is positive but is is obviously not equal to the work done by the battery.
So where does the rest of the energy go?

The parallel plates are attracted to one another and the force of attraction is in the same direction as the movement of the plates so that force of attraction between the parallel plates does positive mechanical work.
If whatever held the parallel plates apart was removed then the parallel plates would be attracted together and that force of attraction would result in the parallel plates gaining kinetic energy.

Comment: Thank you so much for this clear-cut example. Much appreciated.